# Why does each image render differently in my list

Tags: c#, wpf, image, list, rendering

So I have a list of Files with an image. So the itemtemplate for an item in the list is:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Width="15" Height="15" Margin="0,0,3,0" Source="/MyProj;component/Resources/file.png"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Path" Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

But Why does each image in the list render differently? Example below:

[image]

As you can see there are slight differences for each image.. Bottom line bolder on some than others. why is this? The behavior I was expecting was that every item would look identical

Comment: How does it behave if you add `Stretch=None` to the Image?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Question is clear, has all info needed (though I admit adding size of source image would be helpful) and poses an interesting problem, no? A detailed explanation of what the underlying reason for this is would be great.

Comment: @stijin `Stretch=None` gives the original size of the image but in the defined Width x Height space, so you only see the top left corner of the image. I will resize the image so it is smaller and try again. Also thanks for supporting the question, I was also wondering why someone would downvote a clear and interesting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"`. Another option is to use an image that is 15 x 15 pixel in size. Either option should work.

**EDIT:**

What happens here is that you for example have a 20x20 pixel images. If you want to render this in a 15x15 px resolution what should your program do with the fact that there is no one-to-one function relating both resolutions? Which pixel should end up in which pixel of the final image? What happened in your case is that WPF sometimes took pixels from the border, being black and sometimes the neighboring pixels which are not. The whole story is called [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). There are various techniques to overcome the different artefact's that originate from a mismatch in pixel resolution while rendering and this is called  [antialising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing). Check out also this nice [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/73704/what-is-anti-aliasing-and-how-does-it-affect-my-photos-and-images/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is so wrong with this answer that it deserves -1?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but *Try adding* sounds like you're not even sure that really is the solution..

Comment: Because I did not reproduce it, nevertheless I thought I could give a helpful hint. Rather than down-voting it could be helpful to give a feedback that it did not help. Because from my experience with WPF both options I proposed should work, because it is normaly related to the resolution of the images.

Comment: Also stackoverflow asks you to leave a comment when down-voting.

Comment: So I got down-voted for a correct answer... But happy I could help :-)

Comment: I have marked this as the answer. Would be nice to understand why this is the case. I'd imaging its something to do with the scaling when making the image small

Comment: Just to clarify... Setting the `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality".` was the fix.. I was able to keep my original image

Comment: I updated my answer and added an explanation and some links about aliasing.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding `Stretch="UniformToFill"` to the image

Comment: The question was about *why* the list isn't rendering items consistently. As it stands, this is a suggestion of a fix, with no explanation. It doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Ok, point taken. Tried to be helpful by suggesting possible solution, but if it is not how it should be done, I'll use comments next time